# UIAlertView changes to landscape when App is locked in portrait only in iOS8

Tags: iphone, ios8, orientation, xcode6, uialertview

I have an app and its orientation is locked as portrait mode, but when I have a UIAlertView and turn the iPhone to landscape, the alert changes the orientation and crops the alert's overlay. Only in iOS8.

Anyone had this error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes I did get this issue. I have developed my code in iOS7 but had to do compatible with iOS 8   also. So I came across [This link](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html). I got my solution as follows:

When you are working with iOS7 UIAlertView works fine but if you are working with iOS8 you have to use UIAlertController. Use this kind of code:

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"8.0"))
 {
   alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Invalid Coupon."  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
 }
        else
       {
        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController    alertControllerWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Invalid Coupon." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


        UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction
                                   actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action")
                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                   {

                                   }];

        [alertController addAction:okAction];

        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Hope this will help you.