# iOS - UIAlertView/ UIAlertController orientation issue in iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, orientation, uialertview

I am facing few orientation issues in iOS 8 or later. If application is in background and in some other orientation, meanwhile some process of my application is finished, it gives an `UIAlertView` to user then my `UIAlertView` orientation is disturbed when it is in foreground.

I am using following code to lock `alertView` orientation.

```
-(void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView{
    // UIAlertView in landscape mode
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
    alertView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(alertView.transform, M_PI_2);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    NSLog(@"didPresentCalled");
}
```

Please give me some suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIAlertView` is deprecated in iOS 8, so you will need to use `UIAlertController` instead.

```
NSString *title = @"Title";
NSString *message = @"Message";
NSString *buttonTitle = @"Dismiss";
if (NSClassFromString(@"UIAlertController") != Nil) // Yes, Nil
{
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:buttonTitle
                                              style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                            handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                            }]];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else
{
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                message:message
                               delegate:self
                      cancelButtonTitle:buttonTitle
                      otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}
```

Comment: what if we have to use UIAlertView? actually you may say that it is requirement.

Comment: i'll appreciate your answer anyway. +1

Comment: Whoever is telling you that `UIAlertView` is 'required' for iOS 8+ needs to be informed that this is not possible. It's deprecated for a reason. My code still uses it but only where it's available.

Comment: That said, you do have another option. When your code is called for displaying the alert view you can check if the app is in the background. If so, set a flag to indicate that when the app becomes active once again then it should display the alert view.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258693/uialertview-changes-to-landscape-when-app-is-locked-in-portrait-only-in-ios8/26261120#26261120) as I have answered this Question.